# How to check if symlink points to an empty folder

Tags: bash, shell

I am currently studying shell scripting on Linux devices during one of my classes and I have managed to get an extra task that so far exceeds my skills.

I was tasked to write a shell script that finds symlinks that point to empty folders. Now the first two parts are easy - I know how to use the `find` command with tests like `-type l` and `-xtype d`. The problem comes from checking if the folder itself is empty. I've asked my teacher but all I've got were cryptic hints about `xargs` or `exec` arguments which I'm actually not allowed to use yet according to the instruction. My best bet so far is to throw the results of the find into a for loop and test the path I get from the link in each loop, but that doesn't seem to work. So far my code looks like this:

```sh
for var in $`find $1/* -type l -xtype d -print`
do
  if [ $`readlink -f $var` -empty ]
  then
    echo $`readlink -f $var`
  fi
done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `-empty` option to find?

```
$ mkdir empty_folder
$ ln -s empty_folder/ symlink
$ find symlink -type d -empty
symlink
```

This could also be done with filename expansion.

```
$ shopt -s dotglob failglob
$ true symlink/*
bash: no match: symlink/*
```

Comment: I'll admit I have no idea what the second part means, but I'll read the manual on that one. As for the first part, I should find ALL symlinks in a selected directory tree, but can you just really use `-type d -empty` to check if a symlink points to an empty folder?

Comment: The full behavior regarding symlinks is given at https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Symbolic-Links, but I'll admit I'm not entirely sure what it's doing.